# How to get Flexbox to allow an input to be 100% width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the following flexbox form powered by bootstrap 4.

https://jsfiddle.net/kkt0k2bs/1/

I have a media query to resize the form elements for smaller display.

On larger displays, I want the form items to be inline, but on smaller screens, I want the form elements to be stacked and at 100%.

The input is not going 100% width on smaller displays... How can I enable the code to get the width to 100% on smaller displays?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-mod">
        <form class="form-inline justify-content-center d-inline-flex">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email..." class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Request an Invite</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-mod {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 63px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.6);

  [type="text"] {
    width: 260px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    .form-group {
      width: 100%;
    }
    [type="text"] {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 0 16px 0;
      display: block;
    }
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have several redundant divs that only make the styling harder ....

Comment: I agree.. not sure how to avoid that given the way React works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
.form-group {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kkt0k2bs/2/)

This tells flex items to share space when on the same line.

But when they break onto separate lines, each will consume all available space.

Comment: This isn't working - the button is still not consuming full width on break.

Comment: Post a demo here or a new question. @OldGreg

Comment: Referencing your demo - it does not stretch the button to 100% on break to mobile. https://www.screencast.com/t/DIlhHYKrbF

Comment: Code was old and broken. Not sure what happened over time. Here, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/y5vprmet/ @OldGreg

Comment: That works @michael-benjamin.  Thank you!  Can you update the answer or doesnt it let you any longer ?

Comment: @OldGreg, The revised demo here in the comments addresses your point, but not the question. The answer works (or worked) for the question when presented. I'll leave as is for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `.form-mod { display: inline-block; }` might be at fault. You could write a media query for smaller screens to change this to `block`.

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 34em and up)
@media (min-width: 34em) { 
  .form-mod {
    display: block;
  }
}
```